# Why I am unable to see Meta Stack Overflow in my Accounts section?

Tags: support, meta

Why I am unable to see *Meta Stack overflow* in my *Accounts* section?

> Will MSO be available after full migration or this should not come in Accounts section.

[image]

Comment: Downvoter can you please comment on this? I was really not aware of this meta site. That's why asked.

Comment: This seems like a valid question to ask with a definitive answer.... downvotes?

Comment: I am not sure why this question has been downvoted.This is a very basic question and I was relay unaware about the fact, Today I first visit meta mathemetics and other meta sites.

Comment: Its really unfairly downvoted

Comment: @nicael I also surprised.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because Meta Stack Overflow is *not* a separate site<sup>*</sup>.

You cannot see Meta Mathematics or Meta Server Fault in that list for the same reason. Per-site metas are not listed as separate accounts, because they simply are not separate accounts.

<sup>*<sub>There *was* a separate Meta Stack Overflow site until yesterday, when it was [renamed to Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014), to make room for a new per-site Meta.</sub></sup>

Comment: Might want to add that MSO is *no longer* a separate site, for anyone who hasn't kept afoot of recent events.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: The site that *was* a separate site is *still* a separate site, but it was renamed to make room for this brand-spanking new per-site meta. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I support this change. But I find it strange that there are separate badges for this site.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: there should be *some* motivation to participate well in Meta, when reputation is not counted.

Answer (score 7):

Because Meta Stack Overflow is now a per-site meta, it won't show up anymore. Other per-site metas also don't show up, and this is the same for Meta Stack Overflow.